# PMD - violation :SuspiciousEqualsMethodName

Tags: java, pmd

I have the following code, and I get PMD violation SuspiciousEqualsMethodName.

I would like to know why this is consider to be a violation?

```
private boolean areEquals(final Object thisObj, final Object thatObj) {
    return thisObj == null && thatObj == null || thisObj != null && thisObj.equals(thatObj);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof AttributeKey && areEquals(this.getEndPoint(), ((AttributeKey) obj).getEndPoint())
            && areEquals(this.getCluster(), ((AttributeKey) obj).getCluster());
}
```

Comment: So which method is PMD saying has the suspicious name?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it is the `final` modifier on `obj` that is triggering this; i.e. the PMD rule is incorrect.

(Without knowing version of PMD you are using, it is not possible to know how the rule is defined.  If you could tell me the version, I could check what the XML for the rule actually says.)

Comment: I'm using maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1

Comment: That's rather old.  But I asked which version of PMD ... not the plugin.